# How to set up the Redmine WS API Key programmatically?

Tags: redmine

I need to enable Redmine WS and then generate and store its API Key during installation time in order to use it later in other scripts (e.g. fetch_changesets). Is there a ruby command to this?

Answer (score 1):

```
/usr/share/redmine/script/runner "Setting.sys_api_enabled = 1" -e production
/usr/share/redmine/script/runner "Setting.sys_api_key = 'abcd'" -e production
```